# How to add style to an element that was not clicked

Tags: javascript

With this code, I get all the selectors and add a style to it on click.How add style to child element, which parent class `childNodes` was not clicked

```js
let openSelect = document.querySelectorAll(".multiselect");
openSelect.forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    item.childNodes.item(3).style.display = "block";
  });
});
```

```html
    <div class="multiselect"><a></a> <a></a> <a>2</a></div>
    
    <div class="multiselect"><a></a><a></a><a>3</a></div>
```

[image: explain]
[explain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qG9rO.png)

Comment: Please try to explain in more detail what you are trying to do. I don't understand it yet.

Comment: Please don't explain what you want to do from a technical perspective. Describe it from what the result will do for the user.

Comment: @connexo  How add style to child element, which parent class childNodes was not clicked

Comment: I want to remove the style from the child block from the select on which there was no click.

Comment: It doesn't help if you keep repeating what you already told us. Describe the functionality you want to achieve, from your grandma's perspective and in her words (I hope she's doing well!). The explanation should start with "when the user picks an element by clicking, they ... ".

Comment: @connexo check the image

Comment: Which of the elements in your screenshot is which HTML element in the code you've shown?

Comment: Put the code of the image file !

Comment: @connexo input is a select ,i click on it. custom div is a child i open him `item.childNodes.item(3)`, i need close second select when first was opened

Comment: *I need the 3rd element* You are aware that `.item(n)` is `0`-based, meaning the 1st element is `.item(0)`, not `.item(1)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
document.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  openSelect.forEach((item) => {
    if(!item.contains(event.target)) {
      item.childNodes.item(3).style.display = "none";
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).